# Is it possible to use Webkit as a framework on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, webkit

I'm developing on iPhone App.And I want to use webkit for browsing.
As you know apple provides webkit(UIWebview). but it just provides extremely limited api like loadpage, back and forward something like that.

So, my question is how can I use webkit engine?
Anybody know? It's ok even if you just know a little hint for this.

Comment: You can use `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to inject JavaScript into the web view; that JavaScript can do a fair bit. But other than that, no. WebKit is off limits to you as a developer on iOS.

Comment: @Jusung Kye, hey can you share how you do this(use of WebKit framework in iOS)?

Comment: @iHungry The limitation what I wanted to use of webkit was editable mode. But UIWebivew  has been providing that feature since apple released iOS5. So I didn't need to figure out about this anymore. I'm using UIWebivew for my app.

Answer (score 0):

Webkit has almost all the features in built for handling requests/responses/rendering websites. If you want to load any JavaScript you can inject it in your page with your own HTML tags or evaluating the JavaScript using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`

All the other request/responses you would need are in custom frameworks like (AFNetworking/ASIHTTP) or Foundation Framework in iOS.

Comment: Thanks lalith. This is very old post. I already have resolved my problem. :) Thank you for taking your time lalith.

Comment: @Jusung Kye oh okay :) no problem